# Daterangepicker select date by weekly

Tags: daterangepicker

Is there a way, to select weekly on daterangepicker?

> E.g if I select December 5 it will select the whole week.

I tried to search for the answer and i found nothing

[image]

if anyone can help much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may create additional field for selection day of week and then you can use value of the field in the isInvalidDate function. You also can point common parent element across parentEl property and from this get access for the field

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#daterangepicker').daterangepicker({
    parentEl: '.row',
    isInvalidDate: function(date) {
      return parseInt($(this.container).parent().find('select').val()) !== new Date(date).getDay();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/latest/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" />

<div class="row">
    <input id="daterangepicker" type="text" />
    <select>
          <option value="1">Mo</option>
          <option value="2">Tu</option>
          <option value="3">We</option>
          <option value="4">Th</option>
          <option value="5">Fr</option>
          <option value="6">Sa</option>
          <option value="0">Su</option>
      </select>
</div>
```